# How to assign non-member column of query to intended rows using Group by in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

In my query, I'm trying to assign `[Rcv-Qty]` column that is created as template column. I need to assign that value to the intended row but I cannot group by because of this column is not member of the table. That's why I can't match my result to the intended row.

The result copies itself to all rows, not only the intended row that I need.

Here is my query.

```
SELECT 
    mto.POS as [POS], mto.MaterialID as [Ident No], 
    mat.MaterialUnitDesc as [Description], mto.QuantityUnit as [Unit],  
    mto.Quantity as [Mto-QTY], req.Quantity as [Req-QTY], 
    (SELECT SUM(inv.InvoiceQTYTakenCount) 
     FROM INVOICE as inv 
     WHERE inv.InvoiceNo != '' 
       AND inv.InvoiceNo != 'UNKNOWN' 
       AND inv.IsometricID = '24200076B20-TK1-0001_0') as [Rcv-Qty], 
    '' as [Inv-QTY] 
FROM 
    MTO_ISOMETRIC as mto
INNER JOIN 
    MATERIAL_LIST as mat ON mto.MaterialID = mat.MaterialID
INNER JOIN 
    REQUEST as req ON mto.RequestID = req.RequestID
INNER JOIN 
    INVOICE as inv ON mto.InvoiceID = inv.InvoiceID
WHERE 
    req.RequestNo = 369 
    AND req.IsometricID = '24200076B20-TK1-0001_0' 
    AND (inv.InvoiceNo = '' OR inv.InvoiceNo = 'UNKNOWN')
GROUP BY 
    mto.POS, mto.MaterialID, mat.MaterialUnitDesc, mto.QuantityUnit, 
    mto.Quantity, req.Quantity
ORDER BY 
    mto.POS ASC
```

The result is in the image:

[image: Query-Result]

`[Rcv-Qty]` column result must be seen in the first record, and the others must be NULL value. (Because of there is no information for them in database.)

Any ideas?

Comment: I would probably create a temporary table and populate it with the query and then add the column values based on the requestid inside a procedure???

Comment: Is you `POS` a unique ID?

Comment: If by first record you mean the record with POS=1, then you can use this expression: `CASE WHEN POS=1 THEN (.. your existing expression..) ELSE NULL END`. This is a strange request though - it sounds like more a formatting requirement

Comment: Actually it could be an alternative but from time to time the records will be changed by the users. So it must be dynamic for me, may be change the type of query or binding two different queries. Any ideas?

Comment: In this query POS numbers won't be duplicated, we can say they are unique in this query only, but they are not primary key in their own tables. (Primary key is different)

For MTO table: MTOID
       Request Table: RequestID
       Invoice Table: InvoiceID
       Material Table: MaterialID

Comment: Well regardless you need to define 'first row'. What in that row defines it as being first? The minimum POS value in the group?